# PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer - New Excel Services data source

Tags: excel-services, performancepoint, data-connection

I'm trying to connect a published Excel workbook as a data source in PerformancePoint Designer, but I'm unable to do so. Here's what I'm doing:

In PPDD, on the Create tab, I click Data Source. I pick Excel Services as the template.  Then I name the DS in the column on the left. Then I enter the URL for the BI-center, like http://myspserver.fqdn/sites/BI-center.
The Document Library drop-down is then populated with all the available libraries, indicating a connection is made.
I select the library called Documents, where the Excel workbook is located.
Then I try to open the Excel Workbook drop-down, but it's empty, thus I'm unable to continue further.

One strange thing is, that if I create a New Report instead of a DS, go through the same steps, the drop-down populates and I'm able to locate the Excel workbooks and then select Named items just fine. However, I need a DS.

Hav you seen anything like this before?

Regards,
Thomas Paulsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use an unattended account?

I don't know if the Unattended Account is actually used in the create reports wizard, that would explain why you get the choices there, since your user have access to the library. But I'm pretty sure(90%) that the Unattended Account is used when creating a new Data Source. And the Unattended Account needs access to the SharePoint site where you have the Excel Workbooks, if not you'll get an empty Excel Workbook drop-down. Double check that the Unattended Account used for PerformancePoint have access to the library. Its not enough with only SQL access when using Excel Service as Data Source afaik.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer to this one was kinda obvious...
Performance Point Service Application is configured to use a specific service account. I had to give it Read access to the library where the Excel workbook was stored. Once that was in place, everything worked out just fine.. :)